Showing a $g\in L^{q}([0,1])$ and proving an inequality for its $q$-norm
I'm working through some problems dealing with $L^p$ spaces and came across this specific exercise:
Let $1<p, q<\infty$ be such that $\frac{1}{p}+\frac{1}{q}=1$. For any $f \in L^{p}([0,1])$, set
$$
g(x)=\int_{0}^{x} f(t) dt.$$
Prove that $g \in L^{q}([0,1])$ and $\|g\|_{q} \leq 2^{-1 / q}\|f\|_{p}$.
I'd like to apply Hölder's Inequality with ($f(t) \cdot 1$) to proceed, but the details are escaping me. Would hugely appreciate a hint on how to efficiently navigate the relevant inequalities!

Can you show how you would like to apply the inequality or what details are unclear?


Rewrite to express integration upper bound as indicator and apply triangle inequality to obtain  $$|g(x)| \le  \int {\bf 1}_{[0,x]}(t) |f(t)| dt.$$
Apply Holder to obtain $$ |g(x)|\le x^{\frac 1q} \|f\|_p.$$
Raise to the power $q$ and integrate
$$ \int |g(x)|^q dx \le \frac 12 \|f\|_p^{q}.$$
To conclude, raise to the power $\frac 1q$.


Thanks for the answer! As for step three, how did you arrive at the factor of $\frac{1}{2}$ after having integrated?

$\int_0^1 x dx = \frac 12$
